# Suppose that X is an exponentially distributed random variable with λ = 0.39. Find each of the following probabilities:

Tags: probability

Suppose that $X$ is an exponentially distributed random variable with $\lambda = 0.39$. Find each of the probabilities: $P(X > 0.34)$

I think the answer should be:
$P(X > 0.34)= 1 - P(X ≤ 0.34)= 1- \left({1 - e^{\frac{-0.34}{0.39}}}\right)= 0.418.$

But, the answer is incorrect. Can someone told me what I did wrong? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I think you want to integrate this:

$P(X > 0.34)= 1 - P(X ≤ 0.34)= 1- \int_0^.34 \lambda e^{-\lambda x}\,dx$.

EDIT:

Note that the density function for the exponential is: $\lambda e^{-\lambda x}$ for $x>0$ and $0$ otherwise.

Solving for the above equation, we have:

$1-\int_0^.34 \lambda e^{-\lambda x}\,dx$

$=1-\frac{\lambda}{-\lambda}e^{-\lambda x} \rvert_0^.34$

$=1-[-e^{-\lambda(.34)}+e^{-\lambda(0)}]$

$= 1-[-e^{-\lambda(.34)}+1]$

$=e^{-\lambda(.34)}$

$=e^{-.39(34)}$

Comment: Did you mean use the density funtion? Is it should be 1- \int_0^.34 1/λ* e^(-λx) dx?I was talked I should able to use Quantile function(1-e^-x/λ) to do the exponentially distributed question??

Comment: See the edit. I think you have the density function wrong.

Answer (score 1):

at some book, $\lambda e^{-\lambda x}\,dx$ = $1/θ e^{1/θx}\,dx$.I think that why the euqation seems wrong at the question.In fact, this two equation is same.